# Why npm package pm2 fails to restart when CPU utilization reaches 80%?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Pm2 fails to restart when CPU Utilization reaches 80%. I noticed that this mostly happens when I send mail.

Do you think this problem is related to a memory leak or nodemailer?

Here I have added my code.

var smtpTransport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
              host: 'myhostname',
              port:  465,
              secure:true,
              tls:{
                rejectUnauthorized:false
              },
              auth: {
                user: <>,
                pass: <>
              }
            })

var mailOptions = {

```
          from:       <<email>>,
          to:   <<email>>,
          subject:  '<<my text>>',
          html:     <<text>>
        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err,res){

            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log(res.response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you are asking a question you should try to provide as much information as possible. Don't worry people will spend too much time reading it. It's better to have more information than not enough. In your case, please provide us with some code. What are you trying to do? How it fails? Perhaps provide some logs?

Comment: You can check in pm2 error log.

Answer (score 1):

Pm2 does not restart your application when it reaches high CPU, you can only specify a memory limit at which Pm2 will restart your app, as specified in the Docs http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/memory-limit/ .

That being said crashing your server when it reaches a high CPU usage caused by executing a workload is not the way to go.

When your server reaches 80% of its capacity it either means that you have unoptimized code/leaks or you need to scale.